# Edit/Update in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I click OK, it doesn't update the record but rather redirects to the other page without the updated having been shown. What is happening now is that it would return blank; not even showing the record that was entered at initial stage. What I was trying to achieve is when the user clicks OK, redirect to the page with the updated record.

**Form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Issue</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-horizontal">


                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, null, new { @id = "itemNumber", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.expense_acccount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })                        

                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.item.expense_account.index, new SelectList(Model.accountlist, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.expense_acccount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>

                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.price, new { @id = "price", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <input type="submit" value="OK" name="OK" class="btn btn-default" />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("IssueItem","Issue")' " class="btn btn-default" />
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    getIssue.item = getIssue.items[id - 1]; //Returns the requested item for editing
    return View(getIssue);
}

public ActionResult Edit(Issue issue)
{
    int indx = issue.item.lineNum - 1;
    getIssue.items[indx] = issue.item;

    return RedirectToAction("IssueItem");

}

public ActionResult IssueItem() 
{
    Session.Clear(); 

    IssueDAO dbData = new IssueDAO(); 

    getIssue.docNumber = string.Concat("IS", DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmddhhmmss")); 
    getIssue.docType = "Issue"; getIssue.inventory_acccount = 5520; ViewBag.StoresReps = dbData.SelectEmployeesByDept("Stores"); 
    getIssue.item = new Item(); 

    return View(getIssue); 
}

private Issue getIssue { 
    get 
    { 
        Issue issue = (Issue)Session["Issue"];
        if (issue == null) { issue = new Issue(); 
        Session["Issue"] = issue; } return issue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone assist me with this question please

Comment: I didn't understand much of it but add `[HttpPost]` on the post method.

Comment: I have [HttpPost]; seems I mistakenly omitted it from the question

Comment: I am thinking here is the issue because I just say redirect to this view return RedirectToAction("IssueItem"); but what else would I need to add

Comment: hey @adiga; is it possible to help

Comment: ok ok...so you want to update the page ...am i correct ?

Comment: That is for the cancel but when I click OK it also redirects and no record is shown

Comment: I want to update a record

Comment: @adiga do you understand my question and could help me out?

Comment: adiga and raja ji is it possible for anyone you to assist with this question; i'm still having the issue of when the function redirects